Trying to codegen some zod types
So I'm trying to figure out a good solution to codegen zod types from object.
Objects when stringified look like this.
{
 Item: {
  Foo: 'z.string()',
  Bar: {
   IsBar: 'z.boolean()'
  }
 }
}

Goal is to remove any quotes for all values because when the file is written using fs, I will have zod objects.
I don't think I can use the JSON.stringify replacer for this as the string values won't have quotes to remove. Is the only way to use .replace on the stringified object, perhaps using regex? Seems like there should be a better way that I am not aware of.
Result should be this
{
 Item: {
  Foo: z.string(),
  Bar: {
   IsBar: z.boolean()
  }
 }
}

